# Socket policies. They're flipping with my mind

Tags: flash, sockets, policy

I'm writing java server for my app.
While i was debugging my flash app, it all was ok.
When i published it and make it load from localhost - it now needs to load security file.

I added that file as a string to my server, which i pass when request from flash comes. I read all data from request till ending null-byte.
I didn't forget about null-byte at the end of file's text.
In flash app there is event listener on socket connection, so the firs command to server is sending when Event.CONNECT fires.
As i can see, this event is't firing. My server passes policy file to client, but client doesn't connect socket to server after policy got by it.

I spend all day trying to fix that. I have no anymore idea, how to do that. Please, help me somebody.

```
String crossdomeinFile = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\r\n" + "<cross-domain-policy>\r\n" + "<allow-access-from domain=\"*\" to-ports=\"*\" />\r\n" + "</cross-domain-policy>\r\n" + "\0";
System.out.println(crossdomeinFile);
ByteBuffer r = ByteBuffer.allocate(crossdomeinFile.getBytes().length);
r.put(crossdomeinFile.getBytes());
chanel.write(r);
```

Comment: Show us the code that doesn't work.

Comment: `String crossdomeinFile = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\r\n"                + "<cross-domain-policy>\r\n" + "<allow-access-from domain=\"*\" to-ports=\"*\" />\r\n"
                + "</cross-domain-policy>\r\n"
                + "\0";
        System.out.println(crossdomeinFile);
        ByteBuffer r = ByteBuffer.allocate(crossdomeinFile.getBytes().length);
        r.put(crossdomeinFile.getBytes());
        chanel.write(r);`code

Comment: Can't format it, sorry. So here i send back to flash socket policy. After some time it gets policy, i get this : [SecurityErrorEvent type="securityError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2048"]

Comment: I use the same port i connect to, 6969.

Comment: Code above is what i have in java server. Before that code i read request from flash till \0 byte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, it all was because of NIO's write works in nonblocking mode, so when i write data to socket, it wasn't transmitted completly.